# How to interrupt a thread in executor service in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I'm creating a batch job in Spring Boot and executing the batch job in a single thread executor service. The code in the nutshell is like this:

Controller:

```
class TestController {
    // Autowired service and the executorService
    @PostMapping
    public Boolean runTask() {
        es.submit(new BatchTask(service))
        return true;
    }
}
```

Task:

```
class BatchTask extends Callable<Void> {
    private BatchService service;
    // Constructor
    @Override
    public Void run() {
        service.runTask();
        return;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
class BatchService {
    private Repository repo;
    public void runTask() {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(someFileHere)) {
           Iterator<String> it = lines.iterator();
           while (it.hasNext()) {
               // Validate record, update database, etc
               if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                   // Log params, etc
                   throw new InterruptedException();
               }
           }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Cleanup, update databases, mark record status as paused in db
        }
        // empty lines here, no process any longer after the catch
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create the test for the interrupted case. The problem is it didn't set the thread interrupted flag even though I called the shutdownNow() method on the executor service or if using a single Thread instance, the interrupt() method causing the process to proceed until the end. I have created a single file that has enough records for a long process for this test.

The test is basically:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();
    es.submit(new BatchTask());
    es.shutdownNow();
    // assert record's status in database should be paused
}
```

Am I missing something here? I'm open to suggestions or better ways to do this. Thanks.

Edit: this is for a graceful shutdown. I'm using MongoDB as my database.

Comment: What do you expect in your test or why do you think it is failing? Whenever you catch InterruptedException, the interrupt flag of the thread is reset to false.

Comment: @chvndb I expect the cleanup process to run (updating the record to paused, etc) if the thread was supposed to be interrupted. The problem is it didn't even go to the catch, it just continues until the end of the file. I don't think I reset the interrupt flag too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem. If I execute this minimal test case, the cleanup part is called as expected.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    es.submit(new BatchTask());
    Thread.sleep(1_00);
    es.shutdownNow();
  }

  static class BatchTask implements Callable<Void> {
    private BatchService service = new BatchService();

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
      service.runTask();
      return null;
    }
  }

  static class BatchService {
    public void runTask() throws IOException {
      try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          System.out.println("not yet interrupted");
        }
        throw new InterruptedException();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Cleaning up: " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I clearly see the message `Cleaning up: true` being printed after a few `not yet interrupted` messages. So my best guess would be that either, your operation is executed faster than the thread is being interrupted. Try putting some sleeps here and there to see what happens. Or your interruption check in your actual code base has a flaw somewhere.